# GTX with maven project creation

Tags: maven, gwt, gxt

im trying to create a maven project with GTX. Im following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QPOAXLGB2Y, but i get error after I create project:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.sencha.gxt:gxt-chart:jar:4.0.2
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.sencha.gxt:gxt-theme-neptune:jar:4.0.2
```

I have no experience with maven, so I would be glad if someone explained me what it is about

Comment: If your PC is behind proxy , then configure proxy details in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You are using the commercial version of Sencha GXT (4.0.2). In this case you need credentials to log in the repository. I think, that's your problem.

More informations can be found here:
http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/getting_started/maven/Maven.html